# Zoom on a <div> container with CSS transform

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

In the project [bigpicture.js](https://github.com/josephernest/bigpicture.js/) / [live demo](http://josephernest.github.io/bigpicture.js/bigpicture.html), I *replace* every element when zooming (by moving them, and changing their font size).  It works.

Now I want to test CSS' nice `transform: scale(...);` feature instead.

In the following test, I would like to :

- zoom the whole `<div id="container">` when user clicks.
- zoom out when user CTRL+clicks.

The problem is that regardless *where* we click, the zoom is done the same way.
**How to zoom *on the point* that has been clicked instead?** (like it already works with my current implementation of [bigpicture.js](https://github.com/josephernest/bigpicture.js/)).

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container"), wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var zoom = 1;

wrapper.onclick = function (e) {
    zoom *= e.ctrlKey ? 1/1.2 : 1.2;    
    container.style.transform = "scale(" + zoom + ")";
}
```

```css
<style>
#wrapper { position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:1000px; height:600px; background-color: #AAAABB; }
#container { position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; width:600px; height:400px; background-color: grey; transition-duration: 0.3s; }
#text { position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; font-size:30px; }
</style>
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="text">Test<div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Important: You absolutely need to go Full Page to understand what it is about.*

*Note: I tried a few things with `transform-origin`, unsuccessfuly.*

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: @vp_arth As mentionned, I already tried `transform-origin` (with `e.clientX`, `e.clientY`) but it did not change anything.

Comment: your `As mentioned` comes after last edit :) read link above carefully. It takes percents. 0 is left, 100% is right edge. You need just recalc your coords to this procents.

Comment: or try to add `px` postfix

Comment: yes @vp_arth ;) I first forgot to mention I had tried `transform-origin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working snippet: you can try by clicking in the parrot's eye, and then cliking somewhere else: it will always be zoomed with the *clicked point* as center of the scaling.

[image]

```js
var current = {x: 0, y: 0, zoom: 1}, c = document.getElementById('container');
window.onclick = function(e) {
  wx = current.x + e.clientX / current.zoom;
  wy = current.y + e.clientY / current.zoom;
  var coef = e.ctrlKey ? 0.5 : 2;
  current.zoom *= coef;    
  current.x = wx - e.clientX / current.zoom; 
  current.y = wy - e.clientY / current.zoom; 
  c.style.transform = 'scale(' + current.zoom +') translate(' + (-current.x) + 'px,' + (-current.y) + 'px)';
};
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; min-height: 100%; }
#container { position: absolute; transform-origin: 0 0;}
#item { position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px; }
```

```html
<div id="container"><div id="item"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRgdq.png"></img></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need also to apply out your current zoom to screen coords:

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container"), wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper"), marker = document.getElementById("marker");
var zoom = 1;

wrapper.onclick = function (e) {
    var x = e.clientX - container.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var y = e.clientY - container.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    console.log(x,y)
    x /= zoom;
    y /= zoom;
    zoom *= e.ctrlKey ? 1/1.2 : 1.2;
    container.style.transform = "scale(" + zoom + ")";
    container.style.transformOrigin = x+"px "+y+"px";
    marker.style.top = (y-2)+'px';
    marker.style.left = (x-2)+'px';
}
```

```css
<style>
#wrapper { position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:1000px; height:600px; background-color: #AAAABB; }
#container { position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; width:600px; height:400px; background-color: grey; transition-duration: 0.3s; }
#text { position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; font-size:30px; }
#marker { position:absolute; width:4px; height:4px; background-color:red; }
</style>
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="marker"></div>
    <div id="text">Test<div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It *nearly* works, but not really: first zoom three or four times on the first "T" of "Test". It works. Now zoom on the middle of the "s": it will zoom, but the scaling won't have the "s" as fixed point (it should be a fixed point!): the "s" will be moved... and will not be under the cursor.